# "Please run: npx browserslist@latest --update-db2" when deploying a Google App Engine app using Google Cloud Build

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, node-modules, google-cloud-build

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:  npx browserslist@latest --update-db2
```

After I deployed my Google App Engine app using Google Cloud Build,
I got the above error. So I ran the command and got this message.

```
npx: installed 6 in 2.26s
Latest version:     1.0.30001237
Installed version:  1.0.30001237
caniuse-lite is up to date
```

And I still get the error above.
Appreciate it if someone could tell me how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Is it a typo in your  `--update-db2` flag? It should be `--update-db` according to [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist). 

If it doesn't work, try full `npm-update`.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my comment as an answer for better visibility.

Try deleting the typo in the `--update-db2` flag. It should be `--update-db` according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist).

If the issue persists, you can update the component with a full `npm-update`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I figured out that I had an issue with my Google Cloud config which was not related to the Browserslist issue.